# wire accidentally pulled out of "pilot light" can I by-pass pilot light?

Tags: wiring

I have an old egg incubator which I was given and it has a circuit board thermostat.. (most are "wafer" systems or digital..)

The circuit board was "burnt" and being older it is difficult to find parts, but I managed to find a circuit board, and being extremely "green" in the electronics field, I took one wire off at a time to make sure I didn't mix anything up. I had almost everything together and one wire the bare part was a bit short, so a family member attempted to strip the wire a bit more and accidently pulled the wire out of the "pilot light" ( the pilot light  shows you that the electronics are working.)

The  wire goes from the circuit board --and joins to a wire that goes down into the pilot light and then those 2 wires join a wire to the heating element.. in 2 different "circuits"
--We attempted to sodder the wire, but it did not work... Does anyone have any idea if the "pilot light can be by-passed straight to the heating element, as I have not been able so far to find a proper replacement "pilot light".. -(I taped the wire together in the picture )--any help would be appreciated..

[image: wires from circuit to Pilot and to element]

Comment: Are there any marking on the pilot light? Voltage or power rating? You might be able to replace with a suitable indicator light with matched ratings.

Comment: Also can you elaborate on “ The wire goes from the circuit board --and joins to a wire that goes down into the pilot light and then those 2 wires join a wire to the heating element”, as it’s a bit confusing to understand.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a standard neon pilot light assembly that you can easily source.

However, the wire being pulled from the pilot lamp (assuming that wire hanging free isn't touching anything) will not prevent the heater from working.

Comment: Lamp housing *does look* "neon-ish". The printing on its side (not read-able in the photo) may help to determine the lamp type. If the lamp **IS** neon, then the two black wires connect to dangerously-high AC voltages. Do be careful!

Comment: thanks for the replies...The electricity goes from the  cord to the circuit board-through the pilot light and then to the heating element, and appears from the wiring, to circle back..( could be wrong)
The paper on the circuit board say 4 Amp--and it is 120 volt although it says it can take higher--would have to re-look at the paper to be sure of what voltage it can take... I wondered if the pilot light might be more than just a indicator light, not sure if there might be a fuse in there or not..( sorry I am a newbie and real green) --Do  pilot lights  have different electrical ratings?

Comment: i tried  to find a pilot light- the one company who had incubators,  they did not have any, and the unit being older the circuit board was leftover equipment. they had left laying around-?ideas where I could find a pilot light?-- also the unit is un-plugged --- it can carry 4 amps which is enough to fry a person--something I am not interested in happening!- years ago I got an electrical burn from a water leak that had entered a light switch (-unknown to me)  --when I flipped the switch i  
 got burned-- Miracle I didn't get more than a nasty burn---thanks for the replies

Comment: Distributors such as Digikey carry pilot lights, the markings on the side and the colour when lit, and hole diameter would help find a replacement, but as I said, the visual indication won’t affect the functionality or lack of functionality.

Comment: thanks for all your comments! I found a local source of pilot lights! The lady said that what she has uses the same voltage etc, so it sounds like it should work!

Comment: when re-installing a pilot light, is there a "positive" or "negative" wire or does it simply flow through the wires and light it up?

Comment: Probably it’s an AC neon or LED lamp with internal resistor and one lead is the same as the other, but there is no way for us to tell for sure from what information you’ve supplied.

Comment: on the new pilot light-- Both "pigtail" leads are black wires with white writing, on them... normally if I understand correctly a black wire with white writing is "positive" where as a totally black wire is  "negative' and both the wires are exactly the same --black with white writing....does this help??

Comment: just to let everyone know--we finally got everything together and the light works and we have heat!! now I have to check the temperature control... thanks for the help!